# JQuery - Dropdownlists selected dependency

Tags: jquery

I need help on dropdownlist options dependency on each other.  Let's say I have two dropdownlists below.

```
<select name="List1" id="List1">
    <option value="">Select Item</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>  
    <option value="d">d</option>               
</select>

<select id="List2" name="List2">
    <option value="">Select Item</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Scenerios below:

1. List2 will list everything as default (no selection in List1)
2. If option "a" or "d" selected in List1, then List2 will still remain same, no option selected.
3. If option "b" or "c" selected in List2, then option 2 in List2 selected, and also user CAN NOT select other options in List2.
4. However, when user selected back "a" or "d", the list go back to default again, and user can select any items in the List2.

Please help with sample codes if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: Show us the code you got so far

Comment: I don't know how. I am trying .... to figure out.

Comment: I think you have a typo in scenario 3. 'If option "b" or "c" selected in List1' not List2.

Comment: You're correct, I made the typo on that.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the logic is very specific, so without knowing more details we can't really generalize. However, this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/PM6J3/) should get you started at least. Here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
// Listen for change event on List1
$("#List1").change(function (e) {

    // Find the selected value from List1
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var $list2 = $("#List2");

    if (selectedValue == 'a' || selectedValue == 'd') {

        // Reset disabled options for List2
        $list2.find("option").removeAttr('disabled');

        // If you want to change the value of List2 back to some default...
        //list2.val('');
    }

    if (selectedValue == 'b' || selectedValue == 'c') {

        // Select option 2 for List2
        $list2.val('2');

        // Disable all other options
        $list2.find("option:not(:selected)").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

To generalize, you should add classes to List1's options (like `class="reset-other-list"` or `class="restrict-other-list"`). Then, instead of checking against specific values, check if an option with that `class` was selected. This will cause less headaches if values change in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with the sample codes. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks again @lebolo. My dropdownlists are not exactly as the ones I posted, but it would be too confusion to post them since they have too many options and scripts to build the list initially. I followed your codes and logic and it works perfectly.